# How do I display the contain of a zipped file from my directory

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter, path, tix

I have a zipped file with multiple text files in it, and I am building a GUI where I would display the content of the zipped file. So far with the code below it only shows the example.zip folder, but not what's inside. How can I get it to show the text files?

```
    import tkinter.tix
    root = tkinter.tix.Tk()

   fs=tkinter.tix.ExFileSelectBox(root,directory=r"C:\Users\lestivi\Downloads\example.zip")
   fs.pack()

   root.mainloop()
```